# WSFederation Signout in MVC 5 app not deleting authentication cookies in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity, ws-federation

I am developing an MVC 5 app using WSFederation authentication. When the user signs out, I use the following code:

```
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
issuer = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.Issuer;
reply = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.Realm;
signOutRequestMessage = new SignOutRequestMessage(new Uri(issuer), reply);
```

I then redirect to "signOutRequestMessage".

This works in Chrome. After signing out, if I navigate back to a protected page, the browser prompts for authentication. However, this behaviour does not happen in Internet Explorer 9. The IE just happily lets the user through to the page!

I also tried calling FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut() but it made no difference.

I tried deleting the FedAuth and FedAuth1 cookies off the Response object, still no difference.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: @tereško I'm having the same issue now using .net core ws federation, did you resolve this issue ? if yes can you tell me how you resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try set cookies expire date to the past.

```
foreach (string key in Request.Cookies.AllKeys)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(key)
    {
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7),
        Secure = true,
        HttpOnly = true
    };
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```